# Do mixed moments determine joint distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\vec{X}:=(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ be an $n$-dimensional random vector where $X_i$ takes values in $[N_i]:=\{0,1,\ldots,N_i\}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Show that the distribution of $\vec{X}$ is uniquely determined by $$\left\lbrace\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{n_i}\right]\,:\,n_i\in[N_i],i=1,2,\ldots,n\right\rbrace.$$

Comment: Do you know how to prove this in the $n=1$ dimensional case?

Comment: Yes! I can write the distribution as a solution to a system of linear equations which has a unique solution. For higher dimension, this method in principle should work. But I don't know if the system will have unique solution. For 1 dimension, this question gives the answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416186/how-many-moments-uniquely-define-a-distribution-with-finite-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint, the details of which you should be able to fill in.

In the $n=1$ dimensional case the matrix of the linear transformation sending a probability distribution to its vector of moments is a Vandermonde matrix, and hence invertible. In the $n=2$ dimensional case the corresponding matrix is the 
Kronecker product $A\otimes B$ of the two $n=1$ matrices corresponding to the
marginal distributions.  Since thee Kronecker product of invertible matrices is invertible, and the moments determine the distribution here, too.  And for $n>2$ the same method works, too.

You have to know that the  $n=1$ matrices are Vandermonde matrices and have to know why they are invertible in your case. You also need  to know the $\otimes$ contruction. (Maybe its easiest to work out the matrix if $n=2$ and $N_1=N_2=2$ or $3$, and see what's going on with $\otimes$.) And then you have to know that the Kronecker product of invertibles is invertible.